# HTTP Post login does not work

Tags: java, android, http, post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to check whether a password for the side http://ipool.ba-berlin.de/main.php is valid or not. Normally the site response with code 302 and redirects either back to the login page or to the main site.

But even when trying the code with the right password the "Location" response header points back to the login page.

Any advice?

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://ipool.ba-berlin.de/main.php" + "?" +String.format("action=%s",URLEncoder.encode("login","UTF-8")));
        HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<>();
        postDataParams.put("FORM_LOGIN_PAGE","home");
        postDataParams.put("FORM_LOGIN_REDIRECTION","");
        postDataParams.put("FORM_LOGIN_NAME","student");
        postDataParams.put("FORM_LOGIN_PASS","supersecretpassword");
        postDataParams.put("FORM_ACCEPT","1");
        postDataParams.put("LOGIN","login");
        postDataParams.put("login","Einloggen");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        Log.d("post", getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Log.e("loc",connection.getHeaderField(URLEncoder.encode("Location", "UTF-8")));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ex", e.getMessage() + "");
    }
```

I tried to recapitulate the request from google chrome as seen below.

```
General
Remote Address:194.94.23.19:80
Request URL:http://ipool.ba-berlin.de/main.php?action=login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily

Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 02 Dec 2015 17:48:22 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location:http://ipool.ba-berlin.de/main.php
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (Linux/SUSE)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.0

Request Headers
   Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:133
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:PHPSESSID=hfhs6ms3m5kp0bv7ihkkadbb70s10kvo
Host:ipool.ba-berlin.de
Origin:http://ipool.ba-berlin.de
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://ipool.ba-berlin.de/index.php?next=&m=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters
action:login

Form Data
FORM_LOGIN_PAGE:home
FORM_LOGIN_REDIRECTION:
FORM_LOGIN_NAME:student
FORM_LOGIN_PASS:putsupersecretpasswordinhere
FORM_ACCEPT:1
LOGIN:login
login:Einloggen
```

Comment: 'Normally the site response with code 302 '. Well what do you get now instead? And what do these codes mean? I see nothing in your Android code that checks for a result code so how do you know? Nor is there any code that reads the resulting page.

Comment: It replies with 302 everytime and returns the login page's address as location. I simply deleted the code for reading out the result because I don't need it. The resulting page is the login page, I tested it a lot of times. Thus something with my request must be wrong.

Comment: '   postDataParams.put("FORM_LOGIN_REDIRECTION","");'. That is not correct as you can see if you inspect that hidden input.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much, I left that part out and it works Now!